# Exponential equation, variable on both sides

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with solving the following equation for *t*

$Re^{vht}=v_1t$ where $R,v,h,v_1$ are constants. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite this as
$$
-\frac{Rvh}{v_1} = -vht\cdot e^{-vht}
$$
Applying the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) we get
$$
W\left(-\frac{Rvh}{v_1}\right) = -vht\\
t = -\frac{W\left(-\frac{Rvh}{v_1}\right)}{vh}
$$
Using the $W$ function isn't much more than a rewriting, but there is nothing else that can be done when we have $t$ both in the exponent and outside it.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Note this is beyond pre-calc}$

Apart from the Lambert Function which @Arthur has mentioned, lets play with some cases where we can assume $vht<<1$ then we can approximate our equation as 
$$
R(1+vht) = v_1t \implies t = \frac{R}{v_1-vhR}
$$
we obviously require $v_1 > vhR$.

But beyond this you would have to apply a numerical scheme to solve this 
$$
R\mathrm{e}^{vht} - v_1t = f(t) = 0
$$ 
which is a classic root-finding problem.